# if statement based on element value and wildcard

Tags: jquery

I am showing and hiding a class based on a select option. I have a constant `File Promoter List` and I need to be able to activate or deactivate these classes based on that plus what comes after it. Like this: `File Promoter List - Health Excel` or `File Promoter List - ARCVAL`

What do I need to do to allow for this in my if statement?

```
if (($('select[name="catDes"]').val() == "Menu Values") || ($('select[name="catDes"]').val() == "File Promoter List")){
    $('.toHide').css("display", "none");
    $('.toShow').css("display", "inline");
} else {
    $('.toHide').css("display", "block");
    $('.toShow').css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to check if one string contains another. In your case you can check that 'File Promoter List' is at the beginning of the value by using `indexOf() == 0`. Try this:

```
var catDesValue = $('select[name="catDes"]').val();
if (catDesValue == "Menu Values" || catDesValue.indexOf("File Promoter List") == 0) {
    $('.toHide').hide();
    $('.toShow').css("display", "inline");
} else {
    $('.toHide').show();
    $('.toShow').hide();
}
```